# How to rename the multiple files within a directory

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to rename the below files

```
Var1DecoderBase.cpp
Var1DecoderDerived.cpp
Var1EncoderBase.cpp
Var1EncoderDerived.cpp
Var1Factory.cpp
```

to

```
Var4Config.cpp
Var4CountDownTimer.cpp
Var4DecoderBase.cpp
Var4DecoderDerived.cpp
Var4EncoderBase.cpp
Var4EncoderDerived.cpp
Var4Factory.cpp
```

---

I tried doing it using `rename` as below, but no success.

```
rename Var1*.cpp Var4*.cpp ./src/
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "*."
```

Comment: Looks like you have Perl rename, not util-linux rename

Comment: `rename --version
Unknown option: version
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]` @muru You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Perl rename, you could do:

```
rename -n 's/Var1/Var4/' ./src/Var1*.cpp
```

With `-n`, it will only print the renames it will do. Run without it to actually rename.

Comment: I got the success messages but when I did `ls` file names didn't change.

Comment: You need to remove the `-n`. That option only prints the renames, so you can verify before actually renaming

Comment: I didn't notice `-n` option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.startswith('Var1') and f.endswith('.cpp')]
for file in files: 
    os.rename(file, file.replace('Var1', 'Var4'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the filenames  in one file and run the below command, As checked it worked fine

```
 awk '{print "mv" " " $1 " " substr($1,1,3)"4"substr($1,5)}' filename| sh
```

Comment: Note that this assumes no spaces or tabs in the input filenames.